# Issue with git tool in ubuntu

Tags: git, github, ubuntu-14.04

It looks like I've an issue with my `git` tool in Ubuntu. I tried to download a `git` from `github` and this is the error that I got:

```
$git clone git@github.com:mattstauffer/savemyproposals.git l5smp
Cloning into 'l5smp'...
The authenticity of host 'github.com (192.30.252.129)' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is 16:27:ac:a5:76:28:2d:36:63:1b:56:4d:eb:df:a6:48.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
Warning: Permanently added 'github.com,192.30.252.129' (RSA) to the list of known hosts.
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
ajay@ajay-linuxGeek:~/Desktop/experimentlaravel5$ git clone git@github.com:mattstauffer/savemyproposals.git l5smp
Cloning into 'l5smp'...
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

How can I fix it? Doesn't ubuntu store OAuth keys? Is there anything wrong with Ubuntu's OAuth system? Or is there anything wrong with `git`?

Comment: Did you properly set up ssh keys? It seems you don't have right ssh key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with OAuth or Ubuntu.

GitHub supports Git operations over two different protocols:

- **SSH** uses URLs that start with `git@github.com`

  - Authentication for SSH is done using [SSH keys](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Shell#Key_management), which must be properly [configured in GitHub](https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys/). This essentially boils down to creating a new SSH keypair (or reusing an old one), copying the public key, and pasting it into the GitHub website.

    If you are already comfortable with SSH and SSH keys this is a great option. But many users prefer to use GitHub without learning about SSH.
- **HTTPS** uses URLs that start with `https://github.com/`

  - HTTPS operations that require authentication will prompt you for your GitHub username and password. This is a more straightforward authentication mechanism for many users, and is the one that GitHub recommends for new users.

If you wish to use HTTPS instead of SSH you'll need to change the URL that you are using. [Toggle the "clone URL" box to HTTPS and then copy that URL](https://help.github.com/articles/which-remote-url-should-i-use/), then use it for your Git operations.

Note that GitHub does support a few other forms of authentication. Third-party applications can use [OAuth](https://developer.github.com/v3/oauth/)  (but the `git` command-line client doesn't use this), and you can optionally enable [two-factor authentication](https://help.github.com/articles/providing-your-2fa-authentication-code/) for added security.

Comment: Okay, I reset my ssh keys, generated new ssh keys, then added new public key to github, then I ran `ssh -T git@github.com` and the output was `Hi <username>! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.`. Thank you :) 
`